# Using theme color in Android

Tags: android, xml

I've defined attributes in my `attrs.xml`, and theme & colors in `styles.xml`. But I cannot get the color through `R.context.getColor()`. The error:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f01009d
```

Related code snippets:

`.java`

```
Context context = MainActivity.getAppContext();
colorOffset = R.styleable.CellColors_cellEmpty;
int colorId = R.styleable.CellColors[colorOffset];
context.getColor(colorId)
```

`attrs.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CellColors">
        <attr name="cellEmpty" format="color"/>
        <-- Additional members deducted -->
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

`styles.xml`

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="cellEmpty">#eee4da</item>
        <-- Additional members deducted -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: What syntax is this `R.styleable.CellColors[colorOffset]`? Where from/how do you do this? Does this even compile?

Comment: @azizbekian It does, CellColors is a static array under style able, and it has `13` hex values, matching the number of members in my `attrs.xml` And `colorOffset` is a value from `0` to `12`, obtained from the `R.styleable.CellColors_cellEmpty` family.